# General solution of a second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am given the differential equation: $t^2\cdot x''-t\cdot x'+4x=\log(t)$ and I have to find it's general solution. I have made the substitution $t=e^s$ and this resulted in this equation: $y''-2y'+4y=s$. Since it's not your normal form of a second order differential equation (i.e. $y''+ay'+by=0$) I don't know how to continue from here.

Comment: You completely miscalculated the substitution, but that is not even the biggest problem with your approach. The unknown is $x$, not $t$. You should look for $x$ in some form (like $e^{Ct}$ with $C\in \mathbb{R}$, for example).

Comment: Your differential equations textbook should describe how to do this.  Start with the solution of the homogeneous DE.  Next you need a particular solution.  If your RHS is not of the proper form to use undetermined coefficients, then use variation of parameters.

Comment: After substitution you should have $ y''-2y'+4*y=s$

Comment: For particular solution let $y_p=As+B$ and find the parameters.

Comment: This is the Second Order Euler Equation, you can find a simple method here https://www.math24.net/second-order-euler-equation/

Comment: @The_lost Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$t^2 x''-t x'+4x=\ln(t)$$
You can deduce directly the solution to the inhomogeneous equation

Substitute 
$$x_p=A \ln (t)+B, x'_p=\frac A t, x''_p=- \frac A {t^2}$$
We have that
$$-A-A+4A \ln(t)+4B=\ln(t)$$
$$\implies A=\frac 14 , B=\frac 1 8$$
So the particular solution is
$$x_p=\frac 14 \ln (t)+\frac 18$$

For the general solution we substitute $t=e^s, s= \ln t$

Note that 
$$x'=\frac {dx}{dt}=\frac {dx}{ds}\frac {ds}{dt}=x'_s \frac 1t$$
$$x''=\frac {dx'}{dt}=-\frac 1 {t^2}x'_s+\frac 1 {t^2}x''_s$$
the equation becomes
$$x''_x-2x_s+4x=0$$
The characteristic polynomial is
$$r^2-2r+4=0 \implies (r-1)^2-3i^2=0 \implies r=1 \pm \sqrt 3 i$$
Therefore the general solution of the homogeneous equation is

$$ x_h(s)=e^s(c_1 \cos (\sqrt 3 s)+c_2 \sin (\sqrt 3 s))$$
Substitute back t variable
$$ x_h(t)=t(c_1 \cos (\sqrt 3 \ln |t|)+c_2 \sin (\sqrt 3 \ln|t|))$$
The general solution :
$$x(t)=x_h(t)+x_p(t)$$
$$ x(t)=t(c_1 \cos (\sqrt 3 \ln |t|)+c_2 \sin (\sqrt 3 \ln|t|))+\frac {\ln t}4 +\frac 1 8$$